# Trying to set all one's in register fields with similiar name in a register

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to set a uvm register fields in `SystemVerilog`. Here are my register fields:

```
TXA
TXA1
RSVD
T4AMP
```

I am interested in setting all ones into the register fields starting with TXA. I have used the below code to use regex

```
uvm_reg_field my_fields;
register1.get_fields(all_fields);
my_fields = all_fields.find(register1) 
with(!uvm_re_match("TXA*",register1.get_name()));    
//I have a loop to loop through the interested fields 
my_fields[i].set('1);
```

But,I see the error:

> Specified value (`0xffffffffffffffff`) greater than field "TXA" size
>   (1 bit)

Can someone please help me out. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message alone, it seems that you tried to assign the value `0xffffffffffffffff` to `TXA`, which can only fit a single bit. So either you assign the wrong value to TXA, or TXA has the wrong type.

By the way, `0xffffffffffffffff` looks like the unsigned representation of `-1`. Are you trying to assign `-1` to TXA somewhere?

If not, please tell in which line the error occurs, and also show us some more parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the shortcomings of `uvm_reg_field` in that all values internally have the width of the typedef `umm_reg_data_t`. which is by default 64 bits. So `'1` gets expanded to 64 ones.

You can do:

```
my_fields[i].set((uvm_reg_data_t'(1) << my_fields[i].get_n_bits)-1)
```